# AJAX with history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, history

I am using Firefox V26.0. A JavaScript will always place an event on all links to make an ajax call on click and load the page asynchronous. The content which will be loaded will be a JSON-string. It´ll parse the string to have all informations (content, page_title and uri).
After that my script calls window.history.pushstate() to change the history of the browser. And then the error is in the source code. The loaded json string will be visible inside the source code in Firefox V26.0.
This only appears if I have the window.history.pushstate() inside my AJAX-success-function.
So be sure, the problem is not

```
$('#ajax_load').html(obj.content);
```

because the error occurs also if this line will be commented out. The loaded JSON will be visible in the source code only if I use pushState()

I really don't know why this appears.

Here is the full code. I only use this script in combination with jQuery, so no other scripts could affect the problem

```
// In combination with jquery-1.9.1.min.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('js');
    $.ajaxLoad = function(href, popstate){
        popstate = typeof popstate !== 'undefined' ? popstate : true;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: href,
                async: false,
                success: function(json){
                    var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
                    /**
                        obj will look like
                        {
                            content   : "content",
                            page_title: "Title of Page",
                            uri       : "/path/to/appliction/"
                        }
                    */
                    $('#ajax_load').html(obj.content);
                    if(popstate == true){
                        window.history.pushState({}, obj.page_title, obj.uri);
                    }
                    document.title = obj.page_title;
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
                    return false;
                }
            }); 
    }
    $(document).on("click", 'a:not(".noAjaxLoad")', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxLoad($(this).attr("href"), true);
    });
});
```

Comment: "And then the error is in the source code" — What error?

Comment: "The loaded json string will be visible inside the source code in Firefox V26.0." — What source code? The source code of the original URL? The source code of the URL you pushed with pushState? Or the serialised live HTML visible through a DOM inspector which is not *source* code at all? Or something else?

Comment: Ok guys, it´s a bit difficult to understand so I can imagine why you don´t understand it. The DOM looks pretty well after that action, but if you click rightclick->view sourcecode you can see the full loaded JSON-string (from the ajax request). This is the error and I really don´t know why. But this isn´t very pretty, because all clients can see the loaded JSON in the sourcecode. BTW: All other stuff works great, like URL change or history change. But the history.pushState() has the described effect...

Answer (score 0):

What if you try with only:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: doesn´t change anything to me, sorry

Comment: Maybe you need to add the property dataType: 'json', to your $.ajax

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using `pushState` to set the URI to the URI of the JSON data.

You need to set it to the URI of the page that you are transforming the original page into (using the data you get from JSON).

If you aren't already, then you need to create that page (probably by duplicating the work the client-side JS is doing with server side code).

Comment: Yes I am using pushState to set the URI of the JSON, because the URI I get from the JSON is nothing else than the href of the link. The only reason why I took this is because it is possible that a server-side forwarding is performed, so the URI wouldn´t be the same as the href-attribute of the link. Is that a problem? I don´t think that it has something todo with this. It´s a relative path to the pages content that was loaded with the JSON, so exactly that it was made for.